# Excel 2007: Refresh data connection and Show/Hide updated filter results

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Using Excel 2007, I have a data connection that automatically refreshes upon opening.  Within my table, the last column is called 'Show/Hide' and is set to 1(show) or 0 (hide).

After the data connection is finished updating the data and some of the 'Show/Hide' values have changed, I still have to manually show everything in the 'Show/Hide' column, then in the filter I have select '1' to show the correct data.

How do I get the 'show/hide' column to automatically refresh when the data refreshes?

Before (showing 2 items):

```
Color   Is Color   Show/Hide
Red        Y          1
Blue       Y          1
Widget     N          0
```

After (showing 3 items after manually adjusting filter):

```
Color   Is Color   Show/Hide
Red        Y          1
Blue       Y          1
Widget     N          0
Black      Y          1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet will be to use a macro.   Either attach it to startup or another trigger like a button.

If you know how to write macros you would use the VB command "ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll"  followed by the a refresh of your filter "AutoFilter.ApplyFilter"  (This is a very basic example, your filter may have a name etc.)

If you don't know VB you can record the macro and perform the operations you want then just play it back.  That should work just as well.

Comment: I cannot use a macro since the spreadsheet will eventually be loaded to a SharePoint site and use Excel Services.

Comment: In that case I don't think you'll be able to use a data connection anyway.   None of the following are supported in excel services in sharepoint; DDE links, external references, query tables, sharepoint lists, web queries, or text queries.   Check out the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms496823(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I am using an Excel Services data connection (.odc) to pull in the data to the spreadsheet into a table, then using the setting the 'Show/Hide' column if certain parameters are met.  If the parameter=1 then I will show the data.  If the parameter=0, then I want to hide the data using the column's filter.  The filter, however, does not update, when the data is refreshed.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get it to work that way. AFIK there isn't a way to refresh the filter automatically. However, you have alternatives, it's hard to know without more detail on what you are actually doing with the data.  You could try filtering the data in the data connection before loading it into excel. Perhaps sending each group to a different range.  -or- Going the other way, you might also consider applying the filter after you have loaded the sheet to sharepoint using using a filter web part.  Of course this all depends on what your main goal is.